# String Manipulation with the difference of two numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a field called StartYear, the value of my field is 2000.
I have another field called EndYear, the value of my field is 2005.

I want to create a field called YearsInTheProgram that has the values 2005,2004, 2003,2002,2001,2000.

Each of my rows have different values, so in essence I would like this field to have the difference of my fields separated my commas.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Answer will be vendor specific.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Server

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllYears] (
    @START BIGINT = 2000,
    @END BIGINT = 2005
) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @RET NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @RET = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4), @START)

    WHILE @START < @END BEGIN
        SET @START += 1;
        SET @RET = @RET + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @START);
    END


    RETURN ISNULL(@RET, '');
END
GO
```

using;

```
select
    startYear,
    endYear,
    dbo.GetAllYears(startYear, endYear) as AllYears
from
    xxxxTable
```

you can update your table;

```
update xxxxTable (AllYears)
select dbo.GetAllYears(startYear, endYear) from xxxxTable
```